# Android - Start activity without launching

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I start one activity without actually launching it on screen?

Comment: How can we understand what you mean if you give no extra explanations?

Comment: For instance: I have 2 activities. Activity A and B. Activity B starts a service as soon it gets launched. But I want to start the service through activity A, so I need to somehow start Activity B from A without showing it on screen

Comment: I was also wondering how to to that. Best solution I found was calling finish() after launvhing my service in activity B.. I really hope you will get a better answer here..

Comment: Simply don't. It sounds like a flaw in your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance: I have 2 activities. Activity A and B. Activity B starts a service as soon it gets launched. But I want to start the service through activity A, so I need to somehow start Activity B from A without showing it on screen

Step #1: Call `startService()` in Activity A.

Step #2: There is no step #2.

If you want to have some common code, where either Activity A or Activity B can start the service, create a static method, or create a base class that both A and B inherit from.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that the Service uses a method inside Activity B. And if I use startService() from Activity A, I get a nullpointerexception, because the values in Activity B haven't been initiated.

Comment: @Carnal: "Yeah but the problem is that the Service uses a method inside Activity B" -- get rid of that. You should *never* be doing that. To clarify, a `Service` should not be trying to call methods on an `Activity`. The `Activity` can be destroyed at any point by Android. If a `Service` can reach the `Activity`, you have a memory leak. I guarantee you that there are better solutions for whatever problem you are trying to solve this way.

Comment: Hello, My problem that is close to the first one is to start my application an an activity that the User choose. So typically, I start ActivityA by default, than ActivityA check preferences and Launch ActivityB,C,D... than ActivityA close. How can I achieve this?